# Error: Can't find Python executable ... (System variables has python set) when using npm-install --save

Tags: python, node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

This happens when I try installing packages for `npm`

The exact error I am getting is :

`gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable ""C:\Users\Amazo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.EXE
"", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`

I do however set the `PYTHON` variable in my `System variables` so im not sure what I am doing wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install python 2.x from https://www.python.org/

During the install make sure to tick the option "Add to PATH".